# Как переопределить phtml в Magento

Tags: magento

Добрый день

Я новичок в разработке под Magento и вот в чем вопрос:
мне нужно сделать модуль, что бы он мог подходить на другие сайты. А задача следующая.
Добавить возле кнопки "Добавить в корзину" еще одной кнопки.

Модуль и контроллер я написал.
Саму кнопку я уже реализовал, но я ее прописал хардкодом.

Подскажите как мне ее прописать в отдельном шаблоне что бы при применении моего модуля кнопка появлялась не изменяя темы сайта.

Другими словами как мне безболезнено (не меняя ядро и базовые шаблоны) переопределить шаблон вывода кнопки addtocart.phtml

Хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

Создаём блок в `code/local/Name_of_your_module/Block/Name_of_block/Name_of_file.php`.
Определяем в `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
    <Name_of_your_module>
        <class>Name_of_your_module_Block</class>
    </Name_of_your_module>
</blocks>
```

Создаём в layout и template этого модуля:

в слое нужно определить ссылки куда вставлять наш блок для корзины не помню, вот так для карточки товара например:

```
 <catalog_product_view> // блок в который вставляем
    <reference name="content"> //ссылка на часть блока в которую мы вставляем свой блок
        <reference name="product.info"> //ссылка на часть блока в которую мы вставляем свой блок, так сказать рекурсивно))
                <block type="showvalue/product_view" name="showvalue_product.view"   //наш блок, его тип и шаблон                      template="showvalue/product/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

вот шаблон этого блока:

```
<?php if ($this->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
    <span>
        <?php echo $this->__('Stock Qty:') ?>
        <?php echo intval($this->getStockQty($this->getProduct())); ?>
    </span>
<?php } ?>
```

как видим этот шаблон просто выводит количество товара для зарегестрированных пользователей, вставляем его в основной шаблон

```
 <?php echo $this->getChild("showvalue_product.view")->setProduct($_product)->toHtml(); ?>
```

и всё готово)

Может не совсем понятно описал, но именно так я делал все работает ок, не нужно переписывать весь шаблон а просто вставляем одну строку и все.

Знаю точно, тебе нужно вставить блок, имхо 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block type="core/template" name="my.new.block" template="folder/button.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Этот вариант не заменит шаблон addToCart, а добавит кнопку отдельным шаблоном рядом.